# EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids()

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I created a node called "Tutorial". When I preview the post before saving it, I received the following error:

> EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7693 of /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/includes/common.inc).

However, the error when submitting a blog (a node created by drupal) is different. Here it is:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1: SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid = ; Array ( ) in eval() (line 10 of /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

and

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() (line 8 of /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

Any help please...

Comment: Looks like something seriously messed with your nodes. Is it clean Drupal installation? Can you identify when it started to fail, what changed then?

Comment: It's not a clean installation. It came from version 5, then 6, then now version 7. I don't know what's the cause of this problem.

Comment: Please add that to your question, with information about the procedure you have used to migrate from 6 to 7. Was it OK in 7 for some time, or started just after migration?

Comment: Sorry but I don't use the preview mode before. I just mentioned that it came from version 5 because you're asking if it was a clean installation.

Comment: Now I know the problem. It was the display suite module that is causing this problem. If I don't enable display suite under manage display >> layout, no error occur. Is there any fix on this?

Comment: Related: [EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type student. in entity_extract_ids()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756618/entitymalformedexception-missing-bundle-property-on-entity-of-type-student-in).

Comment: possible duplicate of [EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node in modal](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100987/entitymalformedexception-missing-bundle-property-on-entity-of-type-node-in-moda)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. In my case I was using following line in node.tpl

```
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_foo');
$sponsored = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_foo', $field[0]);
```

And field_foo was not in all content type.
In Drupal 6 or 5 approach was different to get field values. That's why it was not happening.

Solution was:

```
if($node->type=='story'){
 $field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_foo');
 $sponsored = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_foo', $field[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case: file \includes\common.inc

```
function entity_extract_ids($entity_type, $entity) { ...

-  if (!empty($info['entity keys']['bundle'])) {
+  if (!empty($entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']})) {
```

fixing error.

Comment: 1. DO NOT change Drupal core! 2. That line is already fixed in latest Drupal

Comment: Works for me, I do understand it is risky but this is the only thing which helps me at the moment. Up voted it back.

Comment: You sir, deserve a medal! This shit is not updated in 7.58. The code sucks, the bugs live forever, i'm looking for clues in bug reports that haven't been fixed in 6 - 7 years and are still open and active. You should definitly edit the core, make it work and go for an other CMS ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share the solution on my problem.

I am using [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) and the error is caused by this line:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node') {
```

After changing it to this code:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
```

The error has gone.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your: EntityMalformedException it seems to me that it's to do with Drupal asking for information that is not available at the time.

I had this error when I had a view that was displaying fields from a node that didn't have those fields. I hadn't stipulated the content type that was to be viewed so Drupal assumed that it was all types and when if found a content type that didn't have the fields I wanted to display it crashed(!?) that page and displayed an error similar to yours.

It seems that it's been a persistent error that has not been resolved. I've noticed in the issue queue of many modules and much to the confusion of many people this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You must see in the content type if the fields data type matches with the information type you save. I mean, if you have a field that is integer type you can't insert a text.