# How to print render each term in a vocabulary?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I kinda feel ashamed to ask this but I really did not find any answer on this...

How can I print each term in a given display mode, for instance 'teaser', anywhere I have loaded a vocabulary's terms?

```
<?php
    $vid = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('finder_items');
    $tax = taxonomy_get_tree($vid->vid, 0);

    $tids = array();

    foreach ($tax as $key => $value) {
        $tids[] = $tax[$key]->tid;
    }


    // ?? causes exception
    $tvm = taxonomy_term_view_multiple($tids, 'full', 0, 'de');

    print $terms;

?>
```

I want to fully render them, with all their fields.

Comment: What exception gets thrown?

Comment: @Alex you are missing with two things here 
1.$term_details = taxonomy_term_load_multiple($tids);
2.Rendering the terms array returned by taxonomy_term_view_multiple().Please check if the suggested code works for you,if so you please update the answer that will be help for others looking for something same.

Comment: I've seen your answers, I can do that today evening, unfortunately not earlier and I will :) Thanks so far!

Comment: @Alex Hop you got the mistake (Instead of passing the term ids to "taxonomy_term_view_multiple()", you have to first load the term object using `taxonomy_term_load_multiple($term_ids)`, and than you have to pass this terms object  to `taxonomy_term_view_multiple($terms_oject)`), please let me whether the code worked for you, or if you are facing any issue with it.

I have tested the answer first on my local so there shouldn't issue with the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reason of Error](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85478/entitymalformedexception-missing-bundle-property-on-entity-of-type-node-in-ent):  you were passing the "terms ids" to the [taxonomy_term_view_multiple()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_view_multiple/7).

> **Solution**: First load the term objects using `taxonomy_term_load_multiple()` and pass its result to the `taxonomy_term_view_multiple()` as below:

```
<?php
    $vid = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('finder_items');
    $tax = taxonomy_get_tree($vid->vid, 0);
    // Initilize the array for storing the term ids.
    $tids = array();
    // Check if any term present in voacb, otherwise foreach will throw error.
    if (!empty($tax)) {
      foreach ($tax as $key => $value) {
        $tids[] = $tax[$key]->tid;
      }

      // Get the term obj by passing array of term ids.
      $term_details = taxonomy_term_load_multiple($tids);

      // This will provide you the required result.
      $terms = taxonomy_term_view_multiple($term_details, 'full', 0, 'de');

      // Render each term.
      foreach($terms as $term) {
        print drupal_render($term);
      }
    }  
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be seeing Exception as

> EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type
>   taxonomy_term. in entity_extract_ids()

**[Reason being](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_view_multiple/7):**

> In taxonomy_term_view_multiple($terms,..)
>   $terms: An array of
>   taxonomy terms as returned by taxonomy_term_load_multiple().

```
    $vid = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('finder_items');
    $tax = taxonomy_get_tree($vid->vid, 0);
    if (!empty($tax)) {
      foreach ($tax as $term) {
        $tids[] = $term->tid;
      }
    }

    // Get the term obj by passing array of term ids.
    $term_details = taxonomy_term_load_multiple($tids);
    $terms = taxonomy_term_view_multiple($term_details, 'full', 0, 'de');

   // Render the return array
   foreach($terms as $term) {
     print drupal_render($term);
    }
```