# EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type taxonomy_term

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have strange behavior that when i visit `www.mysite.com/taxonomy/term/516/sdfsdf`

i get

> EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type taxonomy_term. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7788 of /../includes/common.inc).
>       The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

while it should load content of

`www.mysite.com/taxonomy/term/516`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Refer to this link : https://www.drupal.org/node/1778572#comment-6891428

Comment: i am newbie to drupal. can you please guide what i do?

Comment: Have you try to read & understand comments from top to bottom. Please read it first you'll understand what you need to do to solve your query.

Comment: have you installed [field permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module ?

Comment: yes i am using this

Comment: Disable once & then try to access that link. Is it working or not ?

Comment: disabling field permissions, still error.

Comment: Have you just edited texonomy vocabulary name or create fields in texonomy ?

Comment: no i didn't do so...

Comment: Mainly this issue occured when we edited taxonomy vocabulary name or create a new fields in texonomy. What you do before getting this error.

Comment: as far i know, i did nothing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21495/discussion-between-drupal-star-and-nishantp).

Comment: I can't help any more. Wait for other comments.

Comment: i am using panelizer. when i disable panelizer, it wroks fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node in modal](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100987/entitymalformedexception-missing-bundle-property-on-entity-of-type-node-in-moda)

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be an error in

> entity_extract_ids()

in some circumstances the entity info for taxonomy term is wrong ..
(probably with entity translation in my case)

```
function entity_extract_ids($entity_type, $entity) {
  $info = entity_get_info($entity_type);

  // Objects being created might not have id/vid yet.
  $id = isset($entity->{$info['entity keys']['id']}) ? $entity->{$info['entity keys']['id']} : NULL;
  $vid = ($info['entity keys']['revision'] && isset($entity->{$info['entity keys']['revision']})) ? $entity->{$info['entity keys']['revision']} : NULL;

  if (!empty($info['entity keys']['bundle'])) {
    // Explicitly fail for malformed entities missing the bundle property.
    if (!isset($entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']}) || $entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']} === '') {
      throw new EntityMalformedException(t('Missing bundle property on entity of type @entity_type.', array('@entity_type' => $entity_type)));
    }
    $bundle = $entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']};
  }
  else {
    // The entity type provides no bundle key: assume a single bundle, named
    // after the entity type.
    $bundle = $entity_type;
  }

  return array($id, $vid, $bundle);
}
```

this is 1:1 the code (not patched ..), that needs changes. from common.inc

see here for patches: https://www.drupal.org/node/1270340#comment-9890989

**when using EntityFieldQuery and fe. *node_load_multiple* make sure to pass fully loaded entites !**
use *node_load_multiple* and pass that result.